# Android Application Configuration Missing and Android Studio SDK Manager does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio

After downloading Android Studio and opening an existing project, when I went to edit configuration (after trying to run an existing project) but when I attempted to configure it as an Android Application, I did not find the android application option, which when I compared to my other computer, is required to run the program.

Furthermore, I am missing the Android SDK Manager, both in the IDE and on the startup screen. I don't have SDKs installed on this computer, and I think they are needed to run my project, so I kind of want the SDK Manager.

I have also re-installed Android Studio 8 times, including several older versions. I also installed the packages, which do come with SDK tools, and I made sure everything was selected on installation.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it helps: just File -> invalidate caches/Restart

hope it also can be usefull to someone ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Click on File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Answer (score 0):

check the sdk manager present in the location "C:\Users\"user-name"\AppData\Local\Android\sdk"
launch the SDK manager install the package that you needed

paste the link 
 "C:\Users\"user-name"\AppData\Local\Android\sdk"
 [Android Studio>configure>Settings>Android SDK ]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try deleting everything of Android Studio and then installing the latest version. It might be because of the leftovers of the previous versions that caused this problem to occur. The best way is to try restoring your PC to the time you hadn't have Android Studio.

Comment: That appears to have been the issue, somehow my plugins settings were staying across installations. I turned on all disabled plugins and it was fixed. not sure which one did it, but it did work.